# Postgresql: add two values to a column separated by a comma?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm trying to create a column named geo that has a column that combines two randomly generated points. My table looks like this.

```
create table data (
    id SERIAL primary key,
    first VARCHAR(50),
    last VARCHAR(50),
    g VARCHAR(50),
    geo VARCHAR(100)
);
```

Here is my try at generating those random values but get an error because the `INSERT has more expression than target columns`

```
INSERT INTO data (first,last,g,geo)
SELECT substr(md5(random()::text), 1, 7),
       substr(md5(random()::text), 1, 10),
       substr(md5(random()::text), 1, 1),
       (random() * (47.606209 - 25.427152)) + 25.427152 , (random() * (-124.389641 - -69.082237)) + -69.082237
FROM generate_series(1, 20);
```

Does anyone know how to do this? Also, I know geo locations shouldn't be strings but in my case it works perfectly. Thanks

Comment: This looks like GIS work, use [PostGIS](https://postgis.net/) for that. If this represents a point, Postgres has [built in geometric types](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/datatype-geometric.html) such as [`point`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/datatype-geometric.html) type. At minimum use two numeric columns to store the two numbers. Do the formatting when you `select` them.

Comment: @Schwern: I guess that's just there to generate random test data.

Comment: "*INSERT has more expression than target columns" - well your SELECT has five columns, but your INSERT only specifies four.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I know, Because I'm trying to do this `randomNum,randomNum` in just one column but don't know how to

Comment: so the comma is making it think there are 5 columns

Comment: Yes, `randomNum,randomNum` are two columns

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name i need to combine them into one column like `column: randomNum,randomNum`

Answer (score 2):

The comma between the values indicates they are two different columns.

```
INSERT INTO data (first,last,g,geo)
SELECT
  -- first
  substr(md5(random()::text), 1, 7),
  -- last
  substr(md5(random()::text), 1, 10),
  -- g
  substr(md5(random()::text), 1, 1),
  -- geo
  (random() * (47.606209 - 25.427152)) + 25.427152,
  -- ?fifth column?
  (random() * (-124.389641 - -69.082237)) + -69.082237
FROM generate_series(1, 20);
```

If you want to concatenate strings use [`||`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-string.html).

```
INSERT INTO data (first,last,g,geo)
SELECT
  -- first
  substr(md5(random()::text), 1, 7),
  -- last
  substr(md5(random()::text), 1, 10),
  -- g
  substr(md5(random()::text), 1, 1),
  -- geo
  (random() * (47.606209 - 25.427152)) + 25.427152 ||
    ',' ||
    (random() * (-124.389641 - -69.082237)) + -69.082237
FROM generate_series(1, 20);
```

However, storing these two numeric values as a string will make it slow and difficult to use. Instead, use two `numeric` columns to store the two numbers.

```
create table data (
    id bigserial primary key,
    -- Don't put artificial limits on columns, it doesn't save space.
    -- They'll only use as much space as necessary.
    -- Use `text` unless there's a good reason for a limit.
    -- In Postgres, `text` is just an unlimited `varchar`.
    first text,
    last text,
    g text,
    geox numeric,
    geoy numeric
);

INSERT INTO data (first,last,g,geox,geoy)
SELECT
  -- first
  substr(md5(random()::text), 1, 7),
  -- last
  substr(md5(random()::text), 1, 10),
  -- g
  substr(md5(random()::text), 1, 1),
  -- geox
  (random() * (47.606209 - 25.427152)) + 25.427152,
  -- geoy
  (random() * (-124.389641 - -69.082237)) + -69.082237
FROM generate_series(1, 20);
```

Now they can be compared as numbers and they can be formatted as you need.

```
select geox || ',' || geoy from data;
```

Better yet, use the built in [`point` type](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-geometric.html).

```
create table data (
    id bigserial primary key,
    first text,
    last text,
    g text,
    geo point
);
```

These can also be generated as `x,y` strings and cast to a `point`.

```
select (random() || ',' || random())::point;
```

And Postgres has plenty of [built in 2-D geometric functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-geometry.html).

If you want to do real GIS, use [PostGIS](https://postgis.net/).